# 2 unknown pipes in garage, one dripping/leaking

Tags: leak, pipe, garage

These pipes are about 4' tall.  The one on the left is dripping water, it appears to have a valve to turn it off....Can anyone tell me what these are for and if I should turn the valve off?[image: Garage Pipes leading outside]

Comment: My guess would be an old water softener installation which has been removed.  Can you provide more info?    Which side is leaking (the one with the shut off valve (which is ON)?  also, does the plastic thing connect the two sides internally or do they both just terminate into the air?

Comment: Did you try shutting the valve on the LH side?  It's in the OPEN position now.

Comment: They both terminate in the air.  The landlord has called a plumber to come look, she said that it was the water softener, so that is correct.  I did turn it off, however it shuts off all the water to the house as well.  I will probably turn it off after I run the dishes and shower later today.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the comments that it's assuredly a connection point for a water softener that's since been removed.  The top plastic handle provides a bypass for the softener (either when it's broken, or in this case removed).  I would anticipate that if you turn the shutoff valve off, you'll turn off water to a significant part of your house, or possibly all of it if this is on the incoming water line to your building.  Sometimes there will be a separate cold water feed to the kitchen (so you don't cook/drink with softened water) or to outside faucets, but that's not universal..

If you have plans to install a water softener, then keep it there.  If not, then have a qualified person replace that leaky plastic with new permanent copper piping of some sort.